# How to interact with buttons in ExtJS's MessageBox element?

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, extjs, junit

I have a Ext.MessageBox which appears when user clicks a button on my desired url.

```
Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to do that?',function(btnText){
        if(btnText === "no"){

        }
        else if(btnText === "yes"){
             // Do Something
        }
    }, this);
}
```

I want to test 'yes' and 'no' buttons on this message window. As I have no id set for it can anyone tell me how to access these buttons?

I tried something like

```
WebElement y = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[2]/span/span/span[2]"));
```

But it didn't work. I have checked other similar questions on stack overflow as well but it didn't wok for me.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about such kind of MessageBox element:

[image]

Since extjs generates element IDs on the fly, it's not so easy to locate one.

But nevertheless there are some patterns which can help you to interact with buttons:

So what you need to do is first to locate element with help of implicit waiting and then click it:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement yesButton = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.LinkText("Yes")));
yesButton.click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Though I had to increase wait time from 10 to 15 cause at 10 request was failing due to timeout error.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem myself as well. I made use of Chrome [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en) extension to find out the XPath of this "yes" button and used it like

```
WebElement yesButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/a[2]/span/span/span[2]"));

new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
yesButton .click();
```

But solution given by @Viktor is more clean solution and I have accepted his answer as best one.